# Apps only available on subsites or with old users after migration to SP2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, migration

SP2010 to 2013 migration, on-site, not online.

Migrated users see a large list of apps on both the parent site and its subsites.

New (since the migration) users see only five apps on the parent site. Four of these five are available to the migrated users, but one (Access App) appears only for new users.

On subsites, new users see the same list of apps that migrated users see. They also have the one app that the new users do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being an easy fix. For a more complete answer, I want to mention that this was happening on a MySite collection.

I activated the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure and SharePoint Server Publishing features at the MySite site collection level. That brought back most of the missing apps for all MySite users. The last issue was the missing Access App, which has its own feature. On my own MySite subsite, I had the Access App available and this feature was activated on my subsite. But it was not activated at the site collection level. Activating it at the site collection level enabled it for all users.